# What are the radii for the new iOS 7 icons?

Tags: icon, iphone, ios

What are the radii and sizes for the new iOS 7 icons?

Comment: I'd have to assume they're the same as past icons as they're not forcing every developer to create new icons.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the correct icon, looks like the **border radius** is **12px**.

The overall size is **60 x 60px**.

[image: ios7 icon]

Image taken from [DesignBoom](http://www.designboom.com/design/apple-ios-7/)

Comment: This is the issue I am talking about: http://www.cultofmac.com/231487/jony-ive-is-so-obsessive-he-gave-ios-icons-the-same-rounded-corners-as-the-imac/

Comment: @ZackAronson so does that article answer your question? If so, you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a radius. The iOS icon grid, including the corner curve can be easily put together using two ratios. These ratios are the golden section and the square root of two. Determining the points through which the curved corner passes is surprisingly simple. The grid as it is presented by Apple shows how to establish three points of the curve:

1. the point where the curve departs from the horizontal
2. the point where it departs from the vertical, and
3. the point where it intersects the 45 degree line drawn from the centre.

Extending the grid using the ratios mentioned above perfectly establishes two more points through which a line of best fit can be drawn, e.g., a Bézier curve.

[Here](http://www.designbygeometry.com/ios-icon-mask-corner-curve-study/) is a more detailed study on my blog.